# content script to devtools.js to my new panel

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm having a heck of a time trying to get code in my content script to talk to my panel. (This extension adds a new panel to the Dev Tools.) From my content script I can do this:

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.farewell);
});
```

and I can pick it up in a background script no problem.

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
 function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
 if (request.greeting == "hello") sendResponse({farewell: JSON.stringify(sender)});
});
```

But I need my message to be picked up in my devtools JS. That way I can speak to the panel I've added to dev tools. How can I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To Establish connection between [Devtools Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.html) and multiple [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) pages, [Background Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) is used as a mediator. So, idea is to have a channel from `devtools` to `background` and from `background` to `content scripts`. This is **a generic method** needed to handle variable nature of content scripts `execution time`.

You can use following script as a reference for communication between `devtools.js` to `content scripts`.

**manifest.json**

Registered `background`,`devtools` and `content scripts` to manifest file

```
{
    "name": "Inspected Windows Demo",
    "description": "This demonstrates Inspected window API",
    "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "2",
    "permissions": [
        "experimental",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "myscript.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**devtools.html**

Registered `devtools.js` to comply with CSP

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="devtools.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body></body>

</html>
```

**devtools.js**

```
//Created a port with background page for continous message communication
var port = chrome.extension.connect({
    name: "Sample Communication" //Given a Name
});
//Posting message to background page
port.postMessage("Request Tab Data");
//Hanlde response when recieved from background page
port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
    console.log("Tab Data recieved is  " + msg);
});
```

**myscript.js**

```
//Handler request from background page
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender) {
    console.log("In content Script Message Recieved is " + message);
    //Send needed information to background page
    chrome.extension.sendMessage("My URL is" + window.location.origin);
});
```

**background.js**

```
//Handle request from devtools   
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
    port.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
        //Request a tab for sending needed information
        chrome.tabs.query({
            "status": "complete",
            "currentWindow": true,
            "url": "http://www.google.co.in/"
        }, function (tabs) {

            for (tab in tabs) {
                //Sending Message to content scripts
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[tab].id, message);
            }
        });

    });
    //Posting back to Devtools
    chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender) {
        port.postMessage(message);
    });
});
```

## Output

You can see `http://www.google.co.in/` being received in `devtools` page

## References

You can refer the following documentation for further information.

- [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)
- [Background Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html)
- [CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html)
- [Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.html)
- [Message Communication](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html)
- [Extension API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html)
- [Tab API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html)