# Send message from content script to developer tool tab script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to send data from an content script to a developer tools tab panel?
I am writing an extension and need to pass data from the `inject.js` file to my dev tools panel extension.

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["assets/js/inject.js"],
     "run_at": "document_end"
  }
]
```

Comment: Pssst. That's not how you format code blocks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [content script to devtools.js to my new panel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265880/content-script-to-devtools-js-to-my-new-panel)