# Google Chrome extension communicate with Panel

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop a simple Chrome extension. It just have to access to an object **myVar** from my web page and print it into a panel as a table. (I'm using Yeoman generator, so basically everything is there)

```
background.js // to add a runTime.onMessage listener
contentscript.js // to inject custom.js, add a listener to a custom event and fire the runTime.sendMessage
custom.js // to retrieve myVar and dispatch the custom event.
devtools.js // to create the extension Panel

devtools.html // contains just devtools.js
panel.html // basic html structure of my panel, no js.
```

So, what I was able to do is to inject a custom script into the web page and use event listeners and chrome messaging to pass **MyVar**.

What I'm missing is how to interact with the panel, I'm kind of lost.

Once it's initialized I don't know how to debug, access its DOM, communicate with background.js or contentscript.js.

Any ideas?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once it's [the panel] initialized I don't know how to debug, access its DOM, communicate with background.js or contentscript.js.

- To debug it, you can detach the Dev Tools panel into a window and then [invoke Dev Tools for *that*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661243/how-to-debug-chrome-devtools-panel-extension) with <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.
- It's a frame, so it's a self-contained document; to access its DOM you'll need a script in there.
- To communicate, a devtools panel has access to `chrome.runtime` messaging functions to initiate communication with the background, even though it seems that the other way is impossible. It's usual to open a port with `chrome.runtime.connect`, with corresponding `chrome.runtime.onConnect` in the background script, and use it for two-way communication. Bonus, the `sender` object will contain the tab ID that DevTools is attached to.
- Direct communication with a content script is impossible; you need to use the background as a proxy. Here's an [old but thorough answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265880/content-script-to-devtools-js-to-my-new-panel).

Comment: that answer is less confusing than the official documentation, thank you.